# link inside a rel fora slider

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.1.min"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {      
//Execute the slideShow
slideShow();
 });

    function slideShow() {

//Set the opacity of all images to 0
$('#gallery a').css({opacity: 0.0});

//Get the first image and display it (set it to full opacity)
$('#gallery a:first').css({opacity: 1.0});

//Set the caption background to semi-transparent
$('#gallery .caption').css({opacity: 0.7});

//Resize the width of the caption according to the image width
$('#gallery .caption').css({width: $('#gallery a').find('img').css('width')});

//Get the caption of the first image from REL attribute and display it
$('#gallery .content').html($('#gallery a:first').find('img').attr('rel'))
.animate({opacity: 0.7}, 400);

//Call the gallery function to run the slideshow, 6000 = change to next image after 6 seconds
setInterval('gallery()',6000);

}

 function gallery() {

//if no IMGs have the show class, grab the first image
var current = ($('#gallery a.show')?  $('#gallery a.show') : $('#gallery a:first'));

//Get next image, if it reached the end of the slideshow, rotate it back to the first image
var next = ((current.next().length) ? ((current.next().hasClass('caption'))? $('#gallery a:first') :current.next()) : $('#gallery a:first'));   

//Get next image caption
var caption = next.find('img').attr('rel'); 

//Set the fade in effect for the next image, show class has higher z-index
next.css({opacity: 0.0})
.addClass('show')
.animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);

//Hide the current image
current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000)
.removeClass('show');

//Set the opacity to 0 and height to 1px
$('#gallery .caption').animate({opacity: 0.0}, { queue:false, duration:0     }).animate({height: '1px'}, { queue:true, duration:300 }); 

//Animate the caption, opacity to 0.7 and heigth to 100px, a slide up effect
$('#gallery .caption').animate({opacity: 0.7},100 ).animate({height: '180px'},500   );

//Display the content
$('#gallery .content').html(caption);


     }

</script>
<style type="text/css">
body{
font-family:arial
}

.clear {
clear:both
}

#gallery {
position:relative;
height:360px
} 
#gallery a {
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
}

#gallery a img {
    border:none;
}

#gallery a.show {
    z-index:500
}

#gallery .caption {
    z-index:600; 
    background-color:#000; 
    color:#ffffff; 
    height:180px; 
    width:100%; 
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    top: 358px;

}

#gallery .caption .content {
    margin:5px
}

#gallery .caption .content h3 {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:#1DCCEF;
}
```

```
<h1></h1>
<div id="gallery">

<a href="#" class="show">
    <img src="images/2.png" alt="Grass Blades" width="940" height="360"     title="" alt="" rel="<h3>Title</h3>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lobortis interdum     sem, sit amet dictum nisi imperdiet id. Sed augue massa, luctus vel condimentum sed,     vestibulum vehicula dolor. Nulla convallis, ligula in ultricies lacinia, libero neque     blandit neque, a semper diam ante vitae sem.**<a href="">link</a>**"/>
    </a>
```

i need to add a link in the rel attribute 
the above said thing is not working.
so that when a link can be  given in the description at present it is in rel
above as mentioned

so what to do actually this is a slider i am working for building up my website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use single quotes in the rel attribute otherwise you are closing the attribute, which leads to invalid HTML

```
<a href="#" class="show">
    <img src="images/2.png" alt="Grass Blades" width="940" height="360"     title="" alt="" rel="<h3>Title</h3>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lobortis interdum     sem, sit amet dictum nisi imperdiet id. Sed augue massa, luctus vel condimentum sed,     vestibulum vehicula dolor. Nulla convallis, ligula in ultricies lacinia, libero neque     blandit neque, a semper diam ante vitae sem.**<a href='LINK'>link</a>**"/>
</a>
```

Comment: I do not quite understand, what the exact problem is. Could you describe it more precisely or better make a jsFiddle so we can see it.

Comment: [link](http://edutube.in/10/jquery-slideshow.html) if u see the link in the first slider link is back of the the text actually i kept it at xp networking

Comment: You have `float:left` and `position:absolute` on the link, that's why it is hiding. Just remove both.

Comment: if i remove that then the slider images from 2nd onwards are out of the block u can see the [link](http://edutube.in/10/jquery-slideshow.html)  for that

Comment: Then simply override the styles for this link by saying: `#gallery .content a{float:none;position:static}`

Comment: [link](http://edutube.in/10/jquery-slideshow.html) now i have another problem that is the slide is not giving doctor image and it is giving the next image and doctor discription for the first time and after one round of images is compelted it is giving the correct things can u say why please see the link above

Comment: Does anything still no work as you think it should? Just posting the link is a bit confusing.

Comment: [link](http://edutube.in/10/jquery-slideshow.html) now i have another problem that is the slide is not giving doctor image and it is giving the next image and doctor discription for the first time and after one round of images is compelted it is giving the correct things can u say why please see the link above

Comment: The problem is that you have two elements <a class="show"> in your code. Just remove the second one and everything works fine.

Comment: When everything is now working, would you mind to mark my answer as the correct one.

Comment: sorry i have marked it correct thank u for ur help can help with this also [link](http://edutube.in/word4/) the thing is i have moved the side bar upwards but it was hiding under the slider i need it to be on top of the slider

Answer (score 1):

```
//Set the opacity to 0 and width to 1px


$('#gallery .caption').animate({opacity: 0.0}, { queue:false, duration:0 }).animate({width: '1px'}, { queue:true, duration:300 });  

//Animate the caption, opacity to 0.7 and width to 100px, a slide left effect
$('#gallery .caption').animate({opacity: 0.7},100 ).animate({width: '600px'},600 );
```

Replace Height with width for a caption slide left to right effect